# iOS custom fonts don't work when build made by xcode bot

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, bots

I have custom fonts working in my app, when I manually produce the build from my github repo.
When my xcode bot (aka continuous integration aka xcode server) produces the build from the same github repo & branch (ie. exactly same source), then the custom fonts no longer appear when the app is running.

I checked the .app that the xcode bot produces, and sure enough I can see the .ttf files in there, and the .plist file correctly points to them. There's nothing being output on the console that indicates fonts are failing to load.

Even stranger, the same xcode server produces the build of a different app, and there, the exact same custom fonts are working fine.

I'm really stuck, any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using moarfonts and not setting fonts programmatically in my code.
XCode server doesn't like this at all. 
SO I had to programmatically set fonts everywhere, after all. bummer.